# How to send clicked button to another Activity optimally?

Tags: java, android, object

I'm have one activity with 10 buttons, and transfer info about button clicked to next activity.

```
    View.OnLongClickListener olongBtn = new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            if (v == btn1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddContact.class);
                intent.putExtra("slot", "slot1");
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (v == btn2) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddContact.class);
                intent.putExtra("slot", "slot2");
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (v == btn3) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddContact.class);
                intent.putExtra("slot", "slot3");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    btn1.setOnLongClickListener(olongBtn);
    btn2.setOnLongClickListener(olongBtn);
    btn3.setOnLongClickListener(olongBtn);

}
```

I want to change it like this

```
String slot = toString(v);
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddContact.class);
intent.putExtra("slot", slot);
startActivity(intent);
```

But when I do it, I get in next activity something like this:

```
android.widget.Button{6548fcd}VFED..CL...P....17.0-147.130 #7f08004f app:id/btnPayman}
```

But i'm expectation name of button object.

Comment: Please consider using Id instead of name!

Comment: Create you own button object, format it's content as u like with the info of the actual button. Makes it implement parcelable, then put it in extra bundle =)

Comment: Hi, I see you're pretty new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps you to get better answer on sucesive questions.

Answer (score 1):

To get name of clicked button use `((Button)v).getText()` method instead of `v.toString()` which return String representation of calling Object:

```
String slot = (Button)v).getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddContact.class);
intent.putExtra("slot", slot);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @berliozz: hhh!!! you mean `String slot = (Button)v).getText().toString();` line not returning text from Button is clicked?

Comment: Yes, when I try to set text in text field with Slot, this field stay empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply send button id.

```
    View.OnLongClickListener olongBtn = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddContact.class);
            intent.putExtra("slot", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }
};
```

On next Activity, you can use a switch in order to know what Button has been pressed:

```
  int buttonId = getIntent().getIntExtra("slot", 0);
    switch() {
        case R.id.firstbutton:
            //Do what you want
            break;
        case R.id.secondbutton:
            //Do What you whant
    }
```

Sending int is better than sending a String because you can use a switch on the receiver activity which is faster than anidated if/else

-----------------------EDIT----------------------

While you are using include tag in order to compose your layout, you should set a different id to every button (at the same time your are setting Button text). You can also use an Integer as a tag for every button, and send that tag to the next activity (instead of id).

Look about view tags here: [View setTag() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int,%20java.lang.Object))

Comment: Please, explain me, if I use ID, that will stay unchangeable in future? After I'm relaunch app?

Comment: Yes, you can use ID without problems. That id is setted on layout file and is mapped to R class automatically. Just be sure to use references to 'R class' (R.id.xxxx).

Comment: I'm have little problem with it solution. I gat every time similar ID. I think that result of using include structure in XML, when I'm create custom block with button and textview and insert it in main activity.

Comment: I that case you should set a different id to every button (at the same time your are setting Button text. You can also use an Integer as a tag for every button, and send that tag to the next activity (instead of id). Look about view tags here:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int, java.lang.Object)

Comment: Thanks, setTag and getTag solve my task. I don't know how to do that tread as complete.

Comment: I have editted my own answer in order to cover the include tag case. You can mark as solved there

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the name of the button, try this:

```
String slot = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddContact.class);
intent.putExtra("slot", slot);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks user pozuelog for solution.
I'm use separate xml files for layout and attach it by include to main_activity.

Result of it, that getId method don't work for me.

solution is set Tag for my buttons.

```
    btn1.setTag(1);
    btn2.setTag(2);
    btn3.setTag(3);

    View.OnLongClickListener olongBtn = new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddContact.class);
                intent.putExtra("slot", String.valueOf(v.getTag()));
                startActivity(intent);

            return false;
        }
    };

    btn1.setOnLongClickListener(olongBtn);
    btn2.setOnLongClickListener(olongBtn);
    btn3.setOnLongClickListener(olongBtn);
```

I think that solution may be optimize, but I'm googlecoder and leave it as is for this time.